# How to Override Magento Add to WishList Widget

Tags: magento2, javascript, wishlist, addtowishlist

I want to Override Magento `add-to-wishlist` `data-action` in Magento 2

i Have Created and Override Core addtowishlist Widget

in my `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    "map": {
      "*": {
        "addToWishlist":  'Magento_Wishlist/js/add-to-wishlist',
        "addToCustomWishlist": "Vendor_Module/js/add-to-wishlist"
      }
    }
};
```

Now in My Custom  `js/add-to-wishlist.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'jquery-ui-modules/widget', // use individual jQuery UI component if your widget is for frontend or base areas
     // 'jquery/ui', // use all 'jquery/ui' library if your widget is for adminhtml area
    'addToCustomWishlist' // usually widget can be found in /lib/web/mage dir
  ], function($){

    $.widget('vendor.addToCustomWishlist', $.mage.addToWishlist, {
        bindFormSubmit: function () {
            var self = this;
             alert("I am Here");

            $('[data-action="add-to-wishlist"]').on('click', function (event) {
                var element, params, form, action;

                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();

                element = $('input[type=file]' + self.options.customOptionsInfo);
                params = $(event.currentTarget).data('post');
                form = $(element).closest('form');
                action = params.action;

                if (params.data.id) {
                    $('<input>', {
                        type: 'hidden',
                        name: 'id',
                        value: params.data.id
                    }).appendTo(form);
                }

                if (params.data.uenc) {
                    action += 'uenc/' + params.data.uenc;
                }

                $(form).attr('action', action).submit();
            });
        },
        _updateAddToWishlistButton: function (dataToAdd) {
            var self = this;
                        alert("I am Here");
            $('[data-action="add-to-wishlist"]').each(function (index, element) {
                var params = $(element).data('post');

                if (!params) {
                    params = {
                        'data': {}
                    };
                }

                params.data = $.extend({}, params.data, dataToAdd, {
                    'qty': $(self.options.qtyInfo).val()
                });
                $(element).data('post', params);
            });
        },
     });

    return $.vendor.addToCustomWishlist;
});
```

I did these Following Magento [Documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html) But not getting any Success

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and refresh cache:

```
"map": {
  "*": {
    "addToWishlist": "Vendor_Module/js/add-to-wishlist"
  }
}
```

In fact, remove this 
"addToWishlist":  'Magento_Wishlist/js/add-to-wishlist'
 from your config variable.